# IntelliJ idea inserting Javadoc at the wrong place

Tags: intellij-idea

Every time I type `/**` and then press<kbd>ENTER</kbd> the javadoc is generated behind the method.

Like this

```
/**
 * 
 * @return 
 */
             private Thing getSomething() {
                  ....
             }
```

Every single time.

How to make it place it properly?

Comment: I don't have a problem with this at all. If you format the code, does it fix it? I'm asking because this could potentially be a problem with your code format settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the setting

Code Style > Java > Do not indent top level class members

After I removed the check on that box it worked.